# Exception while running crystal report on client machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports-2010, sql-server-2012-express

After installing C# windows application on my client's machine using click once deployment everything is working fine except Reports section where crystal report is being used. I am facing below exception as soon as the report tries to load :

```
************** Exception Text **************
CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException: Load report failed. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The document has not been opened.
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.get_ReportAppServer()
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.get_ReportAppServer()
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass.Load(String reportName, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename)
   at Application.Screens.Report.cmbAfterSel_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WmReflectCommand(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Below is the code for cmbAfterSel_SelectedIndexChanged

```
                if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No data found for the selected criteria", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                else
                {
                    CrystalReport1 CR = new CrystalReport1();
                    CR.Load(@"C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Project1\Project1\CrystalReport\CrystalReport1.rpt");
                    CR.SetDataSource(dt);

                    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = CR;
                    crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
                }
```

I have already installed Crystal Reports runtime engine for .net framework.

Ideally the report should open with the data coming from database(SQL server 2012 Express). Reports are working fine in my PC where the development was done.

Comment: Sounds like it doesn't find the report file. Either the path is wrong or there are security preventing you to open the file.

Comment: What is the code of Application.Screens.Report.cmbAfterSel_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) ?

Comment: Below is the code :   if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No data found for the selected criteria");
                }
                else
                {
                    CrystalReport1 CR = new CrystalReport1();
                    CR.Load(@"C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Project1\Project1\CrystalReport\CrystalReport1.rpt");
                    CR.SetDataSource(dt);

                    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = CR;
                    crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
                }

Comment: @ShivangiMittal when adding code please update the question instead of posting comment. Everyone will see it and we understand the flow of comments and question information update.

Comment: @Franck Same is updated.

Comment: @ShivangiMittal You are creating an instance of a custom report. You do not need to call the `Load` method as the report is embedded in your application.

Comment: @Franck I removed `Load` method & tried to run the report after creating new .exe & faced the same exception as mentioned in question.

Comment: @ShivangiMittal Then you have not compiled properly. By getting rid of the `Load()` you cannot have that error anymore. You should be facing an error on the `RefreshReport()` now.

Comment: @Franck I removed `RefreshReport()` as well & then I did the steps :                Build->Rebuild Solution-> Solution Explorer -> Project properties -> Publish Now.   After this, again installed the application after uninstalling the previously installed application on client's PC.   Unfortunately, on running reports I faced the same exception again.

Comment: For more information, CrystalReport properties are as : -   **Build Action - Embedded Resource**    &  **Copy to Output Directory - Do not copy**

Comment: @ShivangiMittal Again the compilation doesn't work. You cannot in anyway get the exception of a line of code you do not have. This is 100% certain that the computer you are referring to is NOT running the source code you are describing.

Comment: @Franck I tried to run my .exe on another PC where the application was never installed & faced the same exception again. Please help.